# Portable web browser fo Windows with a proxy individual

Tags: browser, proxy, portable-apps

I need a portable brower which can be run on Win 8.1.

In my desktop I have a running two browser in time (FF+Chrome). So, Portable FF can't start when I have a running normal version (Only one instance can be run). So I try chromium portable, but in Chrome you can't choose a PROXY for only this browser.

Please, can you advise me a *Portable web browser with independent proxy settings*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does this just fine.

You can run as many instances of Firefox as you want, you just need to use the `-p -no-remote` switch.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile

Answer (score -2):

Try switchyomega at Chrome Web Store. I don't see why it should not work in Chrome Portable.

EDIT: to improve the answer.
Webstore link:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif

In this case, simply add proxy profiles in the configuration and you will have a shortcut for every one of them at the extension menu (the icon of the world besides Chrome menu). When you select the proxy you need, the settings will be applied immediatly. I have been using the former version of this extension (SwitchySharp), now deprecated. The extension have also advanced configuration to automate the switching, but I don't think this is necessary here.

Glad it helped you.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself, for example how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Switchy Omega works good. too. Thanks :) I has a worry about changing proxy in Chrome of his use system proxy settings. As I try extension SwitchyOmega, default proxy hold on and changes was made only in chrome.